# How to store File::Find::name output in an array

Tags: perl

I've managed to extract the filenames of my .txt files, but I'm having trouble storing it in an array.

Filenames:

> sample1.txt sample2.txt sample3.txt

Code:

```
sub find_files {
    my $getfile = $File::Find::name;

    if ($getfile =~ m/txt$/) {
         my @sample;

         ($file, $path, $ext) = fileparse($getfile, qr/\..*/);

         push(@sample, "$file");
         print "$sample[0] ";
     }
}
```

Expected output:

> sample1

Output:

> sample1 sample2 sample3

Comment: Why do you expect to see only one filename? You have a `print` statement which will be executed for every file found.

Comment: I just have to put the `print` statement outside the `if` statement? Sorry I'm new to Perl.

Comment: No, I'm asking why you don't expect the code to print `sample2` and `sample3`  when all .txt files are treated the same.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing each file name in `@sample`, but that array is declared in far too small a scope and is discarded at the end of the `if` block, right after the `print`

This should work rather better. It's also more concise and makes sure that the items found are files, not directories

```
my @sample;

sub find_files {

    return unless -f and /\.txt\z/i;

    my ($file, $path, $ext) = fileparse($File::Find::name, qr/\.[^.]*\z/);

    push @sample, $file;
}

find(\&find_files, '/my/dir');
print "$_\n" for @sample;
```